# I can't make dino jump

Tags: javascript, html, css

the complete code is on gitgub. [full code on github](https://github.com/Alissontelez/Dinito_Game) the chrome game dino, dino is not jumping. thats handle key up:

```
function handleKeyUp(event){
    if (event.KeyCode === 32) {
        if (!isJumping) {
            jump();
        }
    }
}
```

and that's jump function:

```
function jump() {
    isJumping = true;

    let upInterval = setInterval (() => {
        if (position >= 150) {
            clearInterval(upInterval);
             //descendo
             let downInterval = setInterval(() => {
                 if (position <= 0) {
                     clearInterval(downInterval);
                     isJumping = false;
                 }
                 else {
                 position -= 20;
                 dinito.sytle.bottom = position + 'px';
                 }
             }, 20);
        }
        else {
        //subindo
        position += 20;
        dinito.sytle.bottom = position + 'px';
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

Comment: You never set `isJumping` to false at the end of your code

Comment: And the github code is very incomplete

Comment: Could you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your HTML and CSS? (It should be able to compile for us!)

Comment: @Rojo compile ?

Comment: @github is comple, with the html and css

Comment: The Github is not complete. The [script.js](https://github.com/Alissontelez/Dinito_Game/blob/master/script.js) is 16 lines long while the code you have provided here is much longer.

Comment: @frederic I should be able to put it into codepen and it should run without errors.

Comment: @Rojo then just say run instead of compile please

Comment: Another problem would be the placement of you script. Rather placing `<script>` in `<head>` place it at the end of your `<body>`. This will make sure that everything loads and `querySelector` will work.

Comment: @Rojo or use window.onload

Comment: @frederic I didn't want to say run because the dinosaur will run, so it run has an ambiguous meaning. Compile has the same meaning in this case and doesn't have an ambiguous meaning

Comment: @frederic that's a good option as well, but I don't like it since other scripts won't be able to access those variables. You could write the variables outside, but my way is easier to explain and change. Up to OP though, of course.

Comment: @Rojo ok, a code running about in the city would maybe not be very funny ... (it hasn't got eyes)

Comment: @Rojo sorry about github, I am gona update

Comment: i put on codepen: https://codepen.io/AlissonTelez/pen/Exgzgxe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've spelt style incorrectly.

```
dinito.sytle.bottom
```

Should be

```
dinito.style.bottom
```

This appears in 2 places.

Your github doesn't seems to be up to date so I've added bits to get it working.

Declaring variables with initial values...

```
var position = 0;
var isJumping = false;
var dinito = document.getElementById("dinito");
```

Added an id to dinito

```
 <div id="dinito" class="dinito"></div>
```

Changed the way keycode is obtained

```
 if (event.code === "ArrowUp") {
```

Here is a working fiddle of all the above changes: https://jsfiddle.net/4cs97fmk/

If it doesn't work then you need to click on the page before keyboard event start working.

Comment: I make the changes, but still not working

Comment: Made more changes + added jsfiddle to demo applying these changes does work. Note: you need to click on the white background in jsfiddle to gain the input focus so that the keyboard event work.

Comment: I going to check

Comment: I put on codepen: https://codepen.io/AlissonTelez/pen/Exgzgxe

Comment: If you put if (event.code === "ArrowUp") { in your codepen. It'll work. You have to click on the page to gain the keyboard focus.

Comment: thanks, it works, but why dont works with space '32'?

Comment: My mistake, change it to if (event.code === "Space") { and it will work with space